# Make notifications from the Stack Exchange app compatible with smart watches

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I personally use the Android app but I'm including the iOS app just in case it applies too.

I have a Pebble and Pebble Time and use it quite a lot.  Since the Stack Exchange app came out, it was great for being notified when you get a response of some kind, on the phone.  I can see it in the notifications area.  However, the way the notifications are generated, the Pebble/Pebble Time apps cannot receive the notifications and therefore cannot send it to my watch.  It works well enough for some other third party apps but I would really like it to work with the Stack Exchange app too.

**Is there something you guys can do to make these notifications compatible with Pebble and smart watches in general?**

I was thinking it was a OS specific version problem, but I've used it across Android 4.2 and 5.1 but it didn't work for me on either.  In the case of 5.1, I'm just not getting notifications period, which is something I'll have to work out.

Comment: This is a really good idea - if I had a smart watch, it would be great if I could get notifications on it. Rep changes would be great too.

Comment: What features would you expect this to have? I've wanted to do this for a while but I couldn't decide on what the proper action buttons to supply with the notification should be. I think the expected behavior would be at least a "Show Post" button that opens the app on your phone, but that seems really limited and not very useful imo.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Honestly I'm just looking for basic support right now. If the notifications could just get to the watch, that would be a good start. The way I understand it is the Pebble app monitors notifications from the system and third party apps and forwards them to the watch.  This works for many third party apps (e.g., Amazon, Dropbox) though not all. I'm guessing the way the Stack Exchange app sends the notifications out is done in a way that it is incompatible with how Pebble monitors them. They don't necessarily have to be actionable, but if any, having the "Show Post" action works.

Comment: @JeffMercado hmm then maybe we're not talking about the same thing. I thought you were talking about android wear support which Pebble piggy backs off of I think. I'll take a look and see why it's not going to the pebble.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Pebble definitely can piggy back off of it, the Pebble app even mentions installing the Wear app for better notification support. I think they're using the same APIs. Though at the moment, I can't verify if it is or isn't working, Stack Exchange notifications are just not working on the phone for me on Android 5.1, even after a couple of reinstalls of the app. Notifications still works on my older 4.2 phone. I might bring this up in a support question soon.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: I'm not sure what changed since yesterday or remember what I did exactly to remedy this but I started receiving notifications from the app today on my phone and this time it was making it to my watch.  It's barebones (not actionable, just the text of the notification is sent) but it works.  I'll have to refine the request here, because it appears to be working, but improvements would be welcome.

Comment: Removing the [tag:ios-app] tag because it doesn't appear to apply.  If your Pebble isn't receiving notifications from the iOS app, please [review the instructions from Pebble](https://help.getpebble.com/customer/portal/articles/1191239-setting-up-ios-notifications).